# Enable SSH on Azure AppService - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I can't ssh to the Azure App Service wordpress site and seems it has been disabled within it.

Referred following url to setup the Site.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-wordpress

Any idea on how can i enable this ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh

Comment: @CSharpRocks thanks for the comment. But i am looking way how to access the docker container to edit this sshd_config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable SSH on Azure AppService - Wordpress

> Any idea on how can i enable this ?

*To enable ssh for WordPress settings you first need to create normal webapp with docker container and then we need to deploy WordPress image in container.*

[image]

*After creating the docker container find the command for deploying WordPress docker image.*

- *Check this [document](https://markheath.net/post/wordpress-container-app-service) for more information on docker deployment.*
- *for Docker image deployment check the [official website](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress)*

``console
$ docker run --name some-wordpress --network some-network -d wordpress

```
- *Here are the commands for installing SSH config file*
```

````
cat sshd_config
```
````

- *Here is the output*

[image]